# É possível fazer edições no .apk?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Desenvolvi um app em java, android studio, e vou publica-lo em uma plataforma web minha(desenvolvida também em java).

Só quem tem acesso a essa plataforma são os clientes licenciados e esse controle é efetuado por uma stringkey(Ex: "123456").

O app baixado é genérico para todos os clientes, e oque vai diferenciar os acessos a cada base(cada cliente tem sua base de produtos) será a stringkey. Esta é solicitada na primeira pagina do app: o usuário digita, o app acessa a plataforma, valida e retorna alguns dados(dentre eles a string de conexao do db).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de otimizar este processo(imagine que a stringkey seja longa), não quero o o usuário digite.

Como a plataforma web sabe a stringkey do usuário, gostaria de, no momento do download do apk:

1-Alterar o layout exibido acima(Ex: editKey.setText("123456");) (Tive dificuldade em localizar o edit abrindo o layout no notepad)

ou

2-Gerar um arquivo texto com a stringkey dentro e fazer o app ler este arquivo quando inicializar(o problema aqui é que nao sei onde colocar este arquivo para que o app tenha acesso quando for instalado)

ou

3-Alguma outra saída que solucione o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com arquivo de texto da certo pro seu problema. Voce pode gerar o arquivo na pasta Downloads do celular. Ai depois que voce usar ele com o app, pode apagar o txt e gravar os dados no settings no android.

Voce só precisa checar nessa sua plataforma online, se o cara esta baixando por Mobile, caso true então vc baixa o txt junto do apk.

Comment: Achei a solução boa.

Comment: Você poderia usar tbm um QRCode, contendo essas informações,  na pagina onde baixa o apk, e pelo apk vc solicitaria a leitura do mesmo..